# Newsletter scubscriber grid in Magento rendered incorrect after adding column

Tags: php, magento, zend-framework

In Magento 1.9, I've added an Event Observer, which appends a column with my new database row into BE Grid.
Here's the Observer code:

```
    $block = $observer->getBlock();

    if ($block->getType() == 'adminhtml/newsletter_subscriber_grid') {
        /* @var $block Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Newsletter_Subscriber_Grid */
        $block->addColumnAfter('subscriber_name', array(
            'header'    => 'Name',
            'type'      => 'text',
            'index'     => 'subscriber_name',
        ), 'subscriber_id');
    }
```

It seems to work fine, it actually does add a column to the grid, but it messes up the table rendering badly: http://i.gyazo.com/fce047033a056ffac26913b3565dfbc9.png
How can this rendering issue be fixed? Why does it mess up this way?

*initial solution was taken from http://www.atwix.com/magento/add-column-to-customers-grid-alternative-way/

Comment: Solved by myself: type => 'plaintext'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
'header'    => 'Name',
'type'      => 'plaintext',
'index'     => 'subscriber_name',
```